# How do I apply style to the outer child of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="citation">
  <span>some text 
        <span id="innerSpan">inner text</span>
        some more text
  </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to affect the outer span of a div with `citation` class, but not the inner span:

```
.citation {
   color:red;
}

.citation span {
   color: yellow
}
```

I've tried :first-of-type, :nth-child, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By selecting the first inner span you'll be selecting the nested span. This makes it difficult (or impossible) in CSS to style the outer `span` but have the `inner` span inherit from the 2nd parent.

One solution would be to apply the same styles to `.citation` and `#innerSpan`, and a different style to the first `span` child, like this:

```css
.citation,
#innerSpan {
  color: red;
}

/* or you could use 
/
/  .citation,
/  .citation > span > span {
/    color: red;
/  }
/
*/

.citation > span {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="citation">
  <span>some text 
        <span id="innerSpan">inner text</span> some more text
  </span>
</div>
```

### Option 2

Definitely not ideal, but a bit of JavaScript would do the trick, like this:

```js
var inners = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.citation > span > span'));

inners.forEach(inner => {
  inner.style.color = window.getComputedStyle(inner.parentNode.parentNode).color;
});
```

```css
.citation {
  color: red;
}

.citation > span {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="citation">
  <span>some text 
        <span id="innerSpan">inner text</span> some more text
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution everything is yellow.  At least on the `Run code snippet` screen.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the question. I've updated the solution, and am looking into another.

Comment: It works, thank you.  Is there a way to do this without directly addressing the innerSpan by ID?

Comment: You could use the `.citation > span > span` selector.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a child selector `>` like this:

```
.citation {
   color: red;
}

.citation > span {
   color: yellow
}
```

Only direct child elements are selected now. The `>` selector looks only one level down the markup structure.

Have a look here:
https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

**color is inherited by children**, you need therefor a reset

```css
.citation {
   color:red;
}

.citation > span {
   color: yellow
}
.citation > span span {
   color: initial; /* or any color you choose */
}
```

```html
<div class="citation">
  <span>some text 
        <span id="innerSpan">inner text</span>
        some more text
  </span>
</div>
```

---

For infos

Snippet uses initial value : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

> The `initial` CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.
>
> ---

If you want the *inner text* **same color as `.citation`**, then add the selector to the rule

```css
.citation,
.citation > span span  {
   color:red;
}

.citation > span {
   color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="citation">
  <span>some text 
        <span id="innerSpan">inner text</span>
        some more text
  </span>
</div>
```